# wp_login action hook not working

Tags: login, actions, publish

I have spent many time looking for a solution to my issue, but in vain. Your help is invaluable.

I am creating a simplified badge system. The goal is to increment the number of badges for a user if he performs some things on the website. For example, for each post published, I give a user one badge.

To do so, I opted for user meta data, and the use of publish_post action hook.

in my `functions.php`, I put:

```
function publish_badge($post_ID) {

   global $current_user; 
   get_currentuserinfo();

   $number_of_badges = get_user_meta($current_user->id,'user_number_of_badges',true);
   $number_of_badges = $number_of_badges + 1;
   update_user_meta($current_user->id, 'user_number_of_badges', $number_of_badges);
   return $post_ID;             
}
add_action('publish_post', 'publish_badge');
```

I am new in using Wordpress action hooks, and I spent a lot of time making it work. I know I am missing something, since for other hooks, the problem remains.

Note I have in total 4 actions for which I want to give users more badges: publish_post,edit_post,wp_login,comment_post.

Your usual help is always appreciated.

**Edit:**

I found solution for all the hooks except wp_login, In fact, I am using custom post types so I should change  my hook names.
in other words, publish_post will become publish_cpt.

What to do with wp_login??

```
    function login_badge($user_login) {
    global $current_user; 

    get_currentuserinfo();
 $number_of_badges= get_user_meta($current_user->id,'user_number_of_badges2',true);
   $number_of_badges= $number_of_badges +5;

  update_user_meta($current_user->id, 'user_number_of_badges2', $number_of_badges);

    }


add_action('wp_login', 'login_badge');
```

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably running into a problem with `$current_user->id` being deprecated since WordPress 2.1. Specifically, I get this notice in the error log:

**Notice**: WP_User->id was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.1! Use WP_User->ID instead. in /xxx/xxx/public_html/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2923.

Use `$current_user->ID` instead. Or you may be able to use [get_current_user_id()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id):

```
add_action( 'wp_login', 'login_badge' );
function login_badge( $user_login ) {
    if ( get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'user_number_of_badges2', true ) )
        update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'user_number_of_badges2', get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'user_number_of_badges2', true ) + 5 );
}
```

**Edit:**  Try also:

```
function login_badge( $login ) {

    $user = get_userdatabylogin($login);

    $number_of_badges= get_user_meta($user->ID,'user_number_of_badges2',true);
    $number_of_badges= $number_of_badges + 30;

    update_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_number_of_badges2', $number_of_badges);
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'login_badge' );
```

Comment: I thank you very much for your information. Unfotunately, I still cannot find solution for my login hook. I will come back here to provide with the solution when I find it. +1

Comment: Both the solution above and changing your code to use `$current_user->ID` worked fine for me on a test web site. How are you testing for success or failure?

Comment: I agree with you, your approach is logical, for me it doesn' work even if I made the change of adding 2 parameters to update_user_meta (get_current_user_id() and  'user_number_of_badges2'). You only put in your solution one parameter( look at my edit). thank you anyway, I also gave the solution for my case above your answer

Comment: You're right. You have to watch me like a hawk. Thanks for sharing your solution. I'm sure some future reader will appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to this thread - it may help someone.
In our case we were referencing functions from one plugging in another.

The issue was the load order of plugins.
One plugin was loaded with 'plugins_loaded' the other with 'init'.
The solution was to properly load and prioritise the load order using the same hook.